# Creating a database table using a CSV file by making PDO calls

Tags: php, pdo, fgetcsv, import-from-csv

I have been trying to create a database by using the first row of a CSV file, however I keep getting an error about my PDO syntax. Apparently something is going wrong with varchar(250) in the `$columns` variable:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(250))' at line 1

The code is below:

```
<?
/********************************************************************************/
// Parameters: filename.csv table_name

$argv = 'seo_domains.csv seo_domains';

if($argv[1]) { $file = $argv[1]; }
else {
    echo "Please provide a file name\n"; exit; 
}
if($argv[2]) { $table = $argv[2]; }
else {
    $table = pathinfo($file);
    $table = 'seo_domains';
}

/********************************************************************************/
// Get the first row to create the column headings

$fp = fopen('seo_domains.csv', 'r');
$frow = fgetcsv($fp);

$ccount = 0;
foreach($frow as $column) {
    $ccount++;
    if($columns) $columns .= ', ';
    $columns .= "$column varchar(250)";
}

$qry = $dbcon->prepare("CREATE TABLE if not exists $table ($columns);");
$qry->execute();

/********************************************************************************/
// Import the data into the newly created table.

$file = $file;
$qry = $dbcon->prepare("load data infile '$file' into table $table fields terminated by ',' ignore 1 lines");
$qry->execute();
?>
```

I changed the `$fp` fopen to a static value instead of using `$file` because apparently the guy who coded the code mentioned above, did not mention how to format the `$argv` variable. Yes, I already tried formatting according to his "Parameters" comment on the first line but still, no avail. I also statically changed the `$table` variable to 'seo_domains' since the `$argv` variable is not being split properly. Instead of re-coding the above code, I am wondering if anyone has any thoughts as to why my database would be resulting in the described error. Any help is appreciated. Just trying to create a table based on first row of the CSV file provided. Upon creation I would like to continue to insert all the row values below row 1 in the CSV, per usual.

Comment: Can you echo out the final `CREATE TABLE if not exists $table ($columns)`

Comment: I can emulate an echo but you cannot echo out PDO prepare statements. Here is the result of : 
`$STMT = 'CREATE TABLE if not exists '.$table.' ('.$columns.');';
echo $STMT.'<br/>';`

Results in : `CREATE TABLE if not exists o (Domain varchar(250), Server varchar(250), IP varchar(250), Username varchar(250), Password varchar(250), Nameserver varchar(250), NameCheap varchar(250), GA varchar(250), WMT varchar(250), SB varchar(250), GAW varchar(250), notes varchar(250), BlankField varchar(250), key varchar(250));`

Clearly "CREATE TABLE if not exists o" is not correct. "o" is what I set $table as.

Comment: try omitting `, KEY VARCHAR(250)` and adding to the start `id int auto_increment`

Comment: Okay, so I moved the $table var outside of the first if statement and was able to at least get the proper if exists "seo_domains" to echo out. 
`CREATE TABLE if not exists seo_domains (Domain varchar(250), Server varchar(250), IP varchar(250), Username varchar(250), Password varchar(250), Nameserver varchar(250), NameCheap varchar(250), GA varchar(250), WMT varchar(250), SB varchar(250), GAW varchar(250), notes varchar(250), BlankField varchar(250), key varchar(250));`

Still getting same error about varchar(250) though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists seo_domains (Domain varchar(250), Server varchar(250), IP varchar(250), Username varchar(250), Password varchar(250), Nameserver varchar(250), NameCheap varchar(250), GA varchar(250), WMT varchar(250), SB varchar(250), GAW varchar(250), notes varchar(250), BlankField varchar(250), id INT KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT varchar(250));
```

Answer (score 0):

`key` is a [reserved](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) word in SQL. See image below

[image]

As you may find that some of the column names in CSV could be reserved words you will need to escape them. In MySQL backticks  are used. ie      `` `key` ``